# '>' symbol whenever I try to copy results of a command to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, redhat

Whenever I try to save the command output to a variable terminal is stuck with a '>' symbol. I tried:

```
n=$(awk 'END{print NR}' 1.log')
```

and
also

```
n="$(awk 'END{print NR}' 1.log')"
```

Every time I have to break the execution using ctrl+c

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a simple typo with a stray `'`.

Try this:

```sh
n=$(awk 'END{print NR}' 1.log)
```

---

The `>` is a prompt and an indication that bash is waiting for you to close the (stray) `'` with a matching `'`.  The exact value printed is held in the `PS2` variable.  The following is from the `bash` manual:

> `PS2    The  value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used as the secondary prompt string.  The default is '> '.`

Comment: See #2 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- such questions should have a comment explaining their solution to the OP, then be closed as caused-by-typo.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed I'll flag for closing.

Comment: Thanks! appreciate the help